# How do I prove this statement about integrable function?

Tags: integration

I have the following problem:

> We assume that $\mu(\Omega)<\infty$. Let $f:\Omega \rightarrow [0,+\infty)$ be a mesurable function. Show that f is integrable iff the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^n \mu\left(\{x|2^n\leq f(x)<2^{n+1}\}\right)$ converges.

I have no Idea how to start in this case. Could someone give me some hints? Although I can't solve it I don't want to read other solutions on the internet, because I want do discuss it and not only reading the full solution.

I hope you could take you some time to give me hints.

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: It looks a lot like the proof of the set of simple functions being dense in the set of positives measurable functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will use the following facts. First one: if $f$ and $g$ are two nonnegative measurable functions, $g$ is integrable and $f \le g$, then $f$ is also integrable and $\int fd\mu \le \int gd\mu$. Another useful fact is the following: let the function $s$ take only countable number of values $s_1, s_2, \dots$ and let $A_n$ be the set $\{x: s(x) = s_n\}$. Then measurability of $s$ is equivalent to measurablity of $A_n$ for all $n$. If $s$ is measurable then integrability of $s$ is equivalent to (absolute) convergence of the series $\sum_{n} s_n \mu(A_n)$. These facts are quite standard in measure theory.

Let's denote the set $\{x:2^n \le f(x) < 2^{n+1}\}$ by $A_n$. These sets are disjonit and $\Omega = \bigcup_{n \ge 0} A_n$.

Assume that $f$ is integrable. Consider function $s$ that takes value $2^n$ on the set $A_n$. This function is measurable since $A_n$ is measurable for all $n$. Also, obviously, $s \le f$. Thus, $s$ is integrable and $\int sd\mu \le \int f$. It remains to notice that $\int sd\mu = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty 2^n \mu(A_n)$.

Now assume that the series $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty 2^n \mu(A_n)$ is convergent. Then also the series $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty 2^{n+1} \mu(A_n)$ is convergent. We consider now the function $s$ that takes value $2^{n+1}$ on the set $A_n$. Then $s$ is integrable and $f \le s$. Thus, $f$ is integrable.